# Is weary a common portmanteau of "wary" and "leary"?

Tags: dictionaries, portmanteau-words

In a comment on a different SE-page, someone misspelt (or intentionally used a different word?) wary, using weary instead:

[image]

Someone else jokingly pointed this out, the original commenter then claimed that *weary is a very common portmanteau of "wary" and "leary"*, and that everyone knows this.

Considering that I had never heard of this before, I attempted googling for weary + portmanteau, but so far I can't say I have found any results indicating that it indeed is a portmanteau.

In addition, neither the [M-W's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weary), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weary), or [Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weary) dictionaries have any definitions or mentions which support the claim.

Am I missing something about how portmanteaus are listed in dictionaries, as to me the aforementioned points strongly suggests that weary is *not* a common portmanteau of wary and leary? Is it indeed a portmanteau?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references _are_ off-topic'. The Online Etymological Dictionary (mentioned as a readily-available resource) shows totally different etymologies.

Comment: In addition, the source's choice of "leary" may be suspect.  Collins suggests that spelling is a regionalism in Britain, while Ngram confirms that "leary" and :"leery" (preferred) diverged in the first decade of the 20th C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exchange is facetious.  The original poster DGS says he has synthesized a chemical that smells like almonds, and he is "weary" of it.  That means that he's tired of it, but what he really means is that he's leery of it, i.e., he's suspicious of it.  And with good reason because HCN (hydrogen cyanide), a deadly poison, smells like bitter almonds.  If there's enough of it around, that's the last thing you're aware of.

TRiG then asks whether DGS means "weary" or "wary", the latter meaning cautious.  DGS realizes his mistake and jokes that "weary" is a combination of "wary" an "leary", the joke being that he's made another "mistake" in misspelling *leery*.

All the words in question have separate origins:

- The *OED* says that *leery* likely comes from the Old English *hleor*, cheek, as a leer, a look askance, was considered a glance over one's cheek.
- The *Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology* traces *wary* through the *-ware* in *aware* and *beware* to the Old English *waer*, to observe.
- The *CODEE* traces *weary* of the Old English *werig* of the same meaning.

Comment: I had a slight suspicion something like that may be the case, but wanted to have confirmation this was the case. The joke falls somewhat flat though, [as leary is an acceptable spelling of leery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leary).

Comment: Will I get in trouble for close-voting as general reference?

Comment: @eirikdaude This kind of banter is difficult to follow because all you've got are the words.  Intonation, facial expressions, and other cues about humor are missing.  It helps if you know a little chemistry, have a long history of fluency in English, and appreciate word play.  Is it even possible to translate into Norwegian, do you think?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Trouble from me?  How would that even work?  As for the CPVPV, I imagine they would award you an oak leaf with clusters.

Comment: While I can see the humor in the penultimate comment, I still have the trouble with seeing it in the final one, but I guess that may just be me. I have enjoyed other humor utilizing puns and word play. As for "translating" it to Norwegian, I have a hard time even coming up with any portmanteaus in Norwegian, and [checking wikipedia](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleskopord#Teleskopord) indicates that most of them are loanwords from English, I am sure you can recognize most of them.

Comment: @eirikdaude I assume you've figured out that DGS doesn't really believe his portmanteau comment that if taken on faith, will absolve him of choosing the wrong word.  He then pretends that TRiG is the one joking in questioning his, (DGS's) word choice because "everyone" realizes that *weary* is correct.  When, of course, nobody would think that.  Alas, the more a joke is explained, the less amusing it gets.

Answer (score 2):

Wary and leery are related to each other, but as you indicate, not to weary. That's the case for their dictionary definitions as well as their common usage. The three words have completely different etymologies.

> **Wary** *adjective*
>   Feeling or showing caution about possible dangers or problems
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wary)
>   Etymology: late 15c., with -y (2) + ware, from Old English wær "prudent, aware, alert, wary," from Proto-Germanic *waraz (cognates: Old Norse varr "attentive," Gothic wars "cautious," Old Saxon giwar, Middle Dutch gheware, Old High German giwar, German gewahr "aware"), from PIE root *wer- (4) "to perceive, watch out for" (see ward (n.)).
>   [- Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wary)
>   **Leery** *adjective, informal*
>   Cautious or wary due to realistic suspicions
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/leery)
>   Etymology: "untrusting, suspicious, alert," 1718, originally slang, with -y (2), and perhaps from dialectal lere "learning, knowledge" (see lore), or from leer (v.) in some now-obscure sense. OED suggests connection with archaic leer (adj.) "empty, useless," a general Germanic word (cognate with German leer, Dutch laar), of unknown origin.
>   [- Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leery)
>   **Weary** *adjective*
>   1 Feeling or showing extreme tiredness, especially as a result of excessive exertion
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/weary)
>   Etymology: related to worian "to wander, totter," from Proto-Germanic *worigaz (cognates: Old Saxon worig "weary," Old High German wuorag "intoxicated"), of unknown origin.
>   [- Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=weary)

Here's [a post](http://jdnnj.livejournal.com/56894.html) by jdnnj of JD's Journal that has a similar summary about these words.

Comment: ...but does not address the issue of etymology (which is ... a portmanteau?' demands).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I took *portmanteau* to refer to an ad hoc composition of parts of words into a new word. I don't know of any proper reference for such compositions other than an urban dictionary. I've added updated the answer with etymology references, though.